# GoogleServices API level changing for earlier than Nougat (API level 24)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-api-levels

I was working on an application in android studios. I added dependencies for google play or google play services. I've installed Android Virtual Device (AVD) with API 28 and I have a mobile cell phone with API 24. When I run the application on the Virtual Device it runs perfectly, but when I run it on my android mobile phone it doesn't run- application does not even start.

What I think is the Google Play targeted API is more than 26.
Question is- Is there any way to run the application on API 24 or earlier?

I've tried my best to change the API level but the google services give an error that it doesn't support the API lower than 26.

```
 android {
     compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
                   applicationId "com.funky.buyit"
                   minSdkVersion 23
                   targetSdkVersion 28
                   versionCode 1
                   versionName "1.0"
                   testInstrumentationRunner 
                   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                   }

   dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.5'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    }
```

It Builds perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a minSdk < 24 it should be fine. I would have a look at the logcat window in Android Studio when you have the real phone connected to your computer. The logs should tell you what the error is on starting up.